# Determining the $POST variables of a submitted form

Tags: forms, commerce

I have a form on my site. Users fill out the form and submit it. When I want to target one of the fields in the form with a custom module I'd target it with something like the following:

```
$form['customer_profile_billing']['field_organization'];
```

But, if I want to target the value a user entered - after they clicked submit, in a custom module, what would be the proper syntax to use, or how would I figure out what my $POST variables are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The submitted values are available in your custom validate/submit handler in the `$form_state['values']` or `$form_state['input']` (with the later one storing raw and unvalidated user input). I think this is considered better practice than accessing the values through the $POST variable.

Comment: Yes, $form_state['values'] is the preferred place to get posted form values 99.9% of the time.